Symplectic current, symplectic form, Hamiltonian and boundary conditions in Wald's formalism
I am learning Wald's covariant phase space (1, 2). Although this formalism is very clear on its purpose, in my opinion, I still have some questions regarding some particular aspects.
We consider a Lagrangian $n$-form  $L$ with volume element $$\varepsilon=\frac{\sqrt{-g}}{n!}\epsilon_{\mu_1\dots\mu_n}dx^{\mu_1}\wedge \cdots \wedge dx^{\mu_n},$$ with $\epsilon_{\mu_1\dots\mu_n}$ the Levi-Civita symbol and $\varepsilon_{\mu_1\dots\mu_n}$ the Levi-Civita tensor that depends on $\phi$, where $\phi=\left(g_{\mu\nu},\psi\right)$ collectively encompass the metric $g_{\mu\nu}$ and matter fields $\psi$.

Symplectic potential, symplectic current and variation of the Hamiltonian: The symplectic potential $\Theta$ emerges when we perform an infinitesimal variation on the Lagrangian $L$ and integrate by parts to find the equations of motion $E$, according to
\begin{align}
 \delta{L}={E}\delta\phi+d{\Theta}.
\end{align}
We recall the definition of the symplectic current
\begin{align}
 {\omega}\left(\phi,\delta_1\phi,\delta_2\phi\right)=\delta_1\Theta_2-\delta_2\Theta_1,
\end{align}
and the symplectic form $\Omega$
\begin{align}
 \Omega\left(\phi,\delta_1\phi,\delta_2\phi\right)=\int_\Sigma {\omega}\left(\phi,\delta_1\phi,\delta_2\phi\right),
\end{align}
where $\Sigma$ is a Cauchy hypersurface with orientation $$\varepsilon_{\mu_1\dots\mu_{n-1}}=n^\nu \varepsilon_{\nu\mu_1\dots\mu_{n-1}}.$$ Here, $n^\nu$ is a unit normal vector pointing to the future of $\Sigma$, whereas $\varepsilon_{\nu\mu_1\dots\mu_{n-1}}$ is a positively oriented spacetime volume form. Then the author postulates that the variation of the Hamiltonian is given by
\begin{align}
\delta H=\Omega\left(\phi,\delta\phi,\mathcal{L}_\xi\phi\right).
\end{align}
Can someone show me why this relation is true? I am unable to see it.

Boundary conditions: The author develops its formalism for asymptotically flat spacetimes. He says that the integral
\begin{align}
 \Omega\left(\phi,\delta_1\phi,\delta_2\phi\right)=\int_\Sigma {\omega}\left(\phi,\delta_1\phi,\delta_2\phi\right),
\end{align}
converges for noncompact Cauchy surfaces, so "'asymptotic flatness' conditions must be imposed upon the dynamical fields $\phi$ (and, hence, on their variations) in order to assure convergence of the integral" (see the discussion below Eq. (45) Ref. (2)). Why? I know that this formalism is now common lore in the determination of gravitational charges, so I doubt that only holds for this asymptotic conditions.



The place to start understanding all this is with finite-dimensional phase spaces. A good reference is chapter 20 of Advanced QFT by V.P. Nair.
Consider a phase space $M$ with symplectic form $\Omega$. This is closed and invertible, i.e.
$$
d \Omega = 0 \quad \text{(closed)} , \qquad i_\xi \Omega = 0 \implies \xi = 0  \quad \text{(invertible)}. 
$$
A canonical transformation is infinitesimally generated by a vector field $\xi$ satisfying ${\cal L}_\xi \Omega = 0$. Using Cartan's homotopy formula, this implies $d( i_\xi \Omega) = 0$. Next, assuming that $H^1(M) = 0$, this implies
$$
i_\xi \Omega = - d H_\xi \tag{1}
$$
$H_\xi$ is defined to be the Hamiltonian charge corresponding to $\xi$.
To understand why this is the Hamiltonian, it is useful to introduce coordinates $q^\mu$ on $M$. In coordinates, (1) reads
$$
\xi^\mu \Omega_{\mu\nu} = - \partial_\nu H_\xi \quad \implies \quad \xi^\mu = \Omega^{\mu\nu} \partial_\nu H_\xi . 
$$
Consider the Poisson bracket of $H_\xi$ with any function $f$,
\begin{align}
\{ H_\xi , f \} &= \Omega^{\mu\nu} \partial_\mu H_\xi \partial_\nu f \\
&= - \xi^\nu \partial_\nu f \\
&= - {\cal L}_\xi f .
\end{align}
Thus, $H_\xi$ defined by (1) is the quantity that generates the canonical transformation on the phase space via the Poisson bracket.
Equation (1) is, in fact, the same as $\delta H_\xi = \Omega ( \delta , \delta_\xi )$. To see this, we note that both sides of (1) is a 1-form, which acts on a vector. Let $\chi$ be an arbitrary vector field. Then, (1) can be equivalently written as
$$
i_\xi \Omega (\chi) = - d H_\xi (\chi) \quad \implies \quad \chi(H_\xi) = \Omega(\chi,\xi)
$$
In this form, it should be clear that this is equivalent to $\delta H_\xi = \Omega ( \delta , \delta_\xi )$.

To answer your second equation, we note that the covariant phase space formalism only applies to finite Cauchy slices $\Sigma$ with finite boundaries $\partial \Sigma$. The asymptotic limit must be well-defined whenever you want to work with asymptotic Cauchy slices. Doing this requires imposition of the right set of boundary conditions. Not every boundary condition automatically leads to finite charges.
